# Not entirely sure how (controller) forwarding works in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to move a bit of code with as function to add pagination to my page, to a certain controller that now looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use AppBundle\Entity\Movie;

class PaginationController extends Controller
{
    public function paginationAction(Request $request, $pageNumber)
    {
        $recordsPerPage = 5;
        $page = $pageNumber;

        // Positioning
        $start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $recordsPerPage) - $recordsPerPage : 0;

        // Query
        //Records:
        //$movies = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Movie')->FindAll();
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Movie');
        //Data to count:
        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('m');
        $query = $qb
        ->getQuery();
        $totalAmountRows = count($query->getResult());

        //For display:
        $query = $qb
        ->setFirstResult($start)
        ->setMaxResults($recordsPerPage)
        ->getQuery();
        $movies = $query->getResult();

        //Pagination: 
        $filterVariables = "";
        //Always round up number (whole pages):
        $totalPages = ceil($totalAmountRows / $recordsPerPage);

        return array(
            'movies' => $movies,
            'filtervariables' => $filterVariables,
            'totalPages' => $totalPages,
            'totalAmountRows' => $totalAmountRows,
            'pageNumber' => $pageNumber
        );
    }
}
```

And the controller that should receive the values looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use AppBundle\Entity\Movie;

class MovieDisplayController extends Controller
{

    public function showAction(Request $request, $pageNumber)
    {
        $this->forward('AppBundle:Pagination:pagination', array(
            'pageNumber' => $pageNumber
        ));

        return $this->render('movies/index.html.twig', array(
            'movies' => $movies,
            'filtervariables' => $filterVariables,
            'page' => $page,
            'totalPages' => $totalPages,
            'totalAmountRows' => $totalAmountRows,
            'pageNumber' => $pageNumber
        ));
    }
}
```

But when I look at the page I see: `Notice: Undefined variable: movies`. How should I change my code so that it knows that I am trying to give the `$movies` variable from one controller to the other?

**Edit:** In order for me to entirely understand the answers below, I want to add the following to my question (thanks to @Rvanlaak):

How should it look like when I want to handle the pagination in my `MovieRepository`?

Comment: Forwarding is not a good practice.

Comment: [Forwarding a request from one controller method to another controller method](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ci2p/forwarding-a-request-from-one-controller-method-to-another-controller-method) and [How to use service, model and factory to create paginated json result in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/yl5h/how-to-use-service-model-and-facotry-to-create-paginated-json-result-in-symfony)

Answer (score 4):

Forwarding a request will result in getting a completely separate response too. In other words, your `showAction` could directly return the return response object of `$this->forward`.

What you are trying to do is not something for a forward, you could handle the pagination in your `MovieRepository`, or even better use a bundle like the [`KnpPaginatorBundle`](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) for that which just requires you to pass the `QueryBuilder`, results per page and active page.

**Edit for additonal question:** In order to let your repository do the pagination, you should [create a custom repository class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) and add a function that returns the expected results based on `$resultsPerPage` and `$activePage` input parameters:

```
// Oversimplified repo
class MovieRepository extends EntityRepository 
{
    public function findAllWithPagionation($resultsPerPage, $activePage) 
    {
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
        $totalRows = $builder->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

        return array(
            'total' => $totalRows,
            'results' => $builder 
                ->setFirstResult($resultsPerPage * $activePage)
                ->setMaxResults($resultsPerPage)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been referenced to that bundle a lot already. I know it exists and I definitely want to try it out sooner or later. Thing is that I already have working code, I only wanted to move it around to make my code look cleaner. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't there be something like `$start = $activePage;` aswell then? Just wondering.

Comment: When I run `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle` command, it only (re-)generates my movie entity, even after adding `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\MovieRepository")`: `Generating entities for bundle "AppBundle"
  > backing up Movie.php to Movie.php~
  > generating AppBundle\Entity\Movie`
Any idea how I am be able to generate my custom repository class then?

Comment: You do not generate a repository, just create the repo class and add it to the `@ORM\Entity()` annotation (as you already did). From then on you can start using it.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

The best place to do this kind of stuff (resources fetching, pagination in this case) is in [a custom `EntityRepository`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes).

Forward an other action doesn't give you an access to the variables of the forwarded action.

In other words, forward `paginationAction` doesn't give you an access to `$movies`, because you don't define it in the original method `showAction`.

You should keep the things at their place by moving all the `QueryBuilder` logic in a `Repository` method that returns only the query results.

But for fix the problem, you need to avoid forwarding. Change the name (could be `getPaginatedResults()`, adapt in when you move it in Repository), remove the Request parameter (keep only the `$pageNumber`).

Then, make the `showAction` looks like :

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $pageNumber)
{
    $data = $this->getPaginatedResults($pageNumber); // Actually $this->paginateAction($request, $pageNumber);    

    return $this->render('movies/index.html.twig', array(
        'movies' => $data['movies'], // Get it from $data
        'filtervariables' => $data['filterVariables'],
        'page' => $data['page'],
        'totalPages' => $data['totalPages'],
        'totalAmountRows' => $data['totalAmountRows'],
        'pageNumber' => $data['pageNumber'],
    ));
}
```

Comment: Maybe @Barrosy uses the `FrameworkBundle` `Template` and `Route` annotation for that, which allows controllers to just return a plain array with data for the view.

Comment: As we can see, he don't (use of `$this->render`). Also, usage of `@Template` is no more recommended in Symfony best practices ... I digress from the main topic. In this case, the things are not in the good place, forward is not what he want.